# Stretch an array and fill nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, numpy-ndarray

I have a 1-d numpy array with length n, and I want to stretch it to m (n<m) and systematically add numpy.nan.

For example:

```
>>> arr = [4,5,1,2,6,8] # take this
>>> stretch(arr,8)
[4,5,np.nan,1,2,np.nan,6,8] # convert to this
```

**Requirements:**
1. No nan's at both ends (if possible)
2. Work for all lengths

I've tried

```
>>> def stretch(x,to,fill=np.nan):
...     step = to/len(x)
...     output = np.repeat(fill,to)
...     foreign = np.arange(0,to,step).round().astype(int)
...     output[foreign] = x
...     return output

>>> arr = np.random.rand(6553)
>>> stretch(arr,6622)

  File "<ipython-input-216-0202bc39278e>", line 2, in <module>
    stretch(arr,6622)

  File "<ipython-input-211-177ee8bc10a7>", line 9, in stretch
    output[foreign] = x

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (6553,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (6554,)
```

Does not seem to work properly (for an array of length 6553, violates req 2, and does not guarantee 1), any clues to overcome this?

Comment: What is the logic behind adding NaNs? How are they positioned?

Comment: 'Systematically' explains it, in other words, evenly spaced (as much as possible). I will handle NaN's in various ways which goes off topic for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`roundrobin` from `itertools` Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))

def stretch(x, to, fill=np.nan):
    n_gaps = to - len(x)
    return np.hstack([*roundrobin(np.array_split(x, n_gaps+1), np.repeat(fill, n_gaps))])

arr = [4,5,1,2,6,8]
stretch(arr, 8)
# array([ 4.,  5., nan,  1.,  2., nan,  6.,  8.])

arr2 = np.random.rand(655)
stretched_arr2 = stretch(arr,662)
np.diff(np.argwhere(np.isnan(stretched_arr2)), axis=0)
# nans are evenly spaced    
array([[83],
       [83],
       [83],
       [83],
       [83],
       [83]])
```

### Logic behind

`n_gaps`: calculates how many gaps to fill (desired length - current length)

`np_array_split`: with `n_gaps+1`, it splits input array into as same length as possible

`roundrobin`: since `np_array_split` generates one more array than gaps, roundrobin-ing (i.e. alternatively iterating) grants that `np.nan` is never at either end of result.

Answer (score 1):

This approach places the non-nan elements at the boundaries, leaving `nan` values at the center, although it won't evenly space the `nan` values.

```
arr = [4,5,1,2,6,8]   
stretch_len = 8    

def stretch(arr, stretch_len):
    stretched_arr = np.empty(stretch_len)   
    stretched_arr.fill(np.nan)
    arr_len = len(arr)

    if arr_len % 2 == 0:
        mid = int(arr_len/2)
        stretched_arr[:mid] = arr[:mid]
        stretched_arr[-mid:] = arr[-mid:]
    else:
        mid = int(np.floor(arr_len/2))
        stretched_arr[:mid] = arr[:mid]
        stretched_arr[-mid-1:] = arr[-mid-1:]

    return stretched_arr
```

Here are some test cases that I tested:

#### Test cases:

```
In [104]: stretch(arr, stretch_len)   
Out[104]: array([ 4.,  5.,  1., nan, nan,  2.,  6.,  8.])

In [105]: arr = [4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 8, 9]    

In [106]: stretch(arr, stretch_len)  
Out[106]: array([ 4.,  5.,  1., nan,  2.,  6.,  8.,  9.])

In [107]: stretch(arr, 9)  
Out[107]: array([ 4.,  5.,  1., nan, nan,  2.,  6.,  8.,  9.])
```

Comment: Two consecutive nans do not satisfy being evenly-spaced condition. I would expect at least 2 samples between them.

Answer (score 1):

Although [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54304506/7184515) resolved the problem, I found a shorter answer, which maybe helpful,

```
def stretch2(x,to,fill=np.nan):
    output  = np.repeat(fill,to)
    foreign = np.linspace(0,to-1,len(x)).round().astype(int)
    output[foreign] = x
    return output
```

very similar to my first attempt. Timings:

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(1000)
>>> to = 1200
>>> %timeit stretch(x,to) # Chris' version
>>> %timeit stretch2(x,to)

996 µs ± 22.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
32.2 µs ± 339 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Check if it works properly:

```
>>> aa = stretch2(x,to)
>>> np.diff(np.where(np.isnan(aa))[0])
array([6, 6, 6, ... , 6])
>>> np.sum(aa[~np.isnan(aa)] - x)
0.0
```

Check boundary conditions:

```
>>> aa[:5]
array([0.78581616, 0.1630689 , 0.52039993,        nan, 0.89844404])
>>> aa[-5:]
array([0.7063653 ,        nan, 0.2022172 , 0.94604503, 0.91201897])
```

all satisfied. Works for all 1-d arrays, and can be generalized to work with n-d arrays too, with a few changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resize` to resize the array.

Once, it is resized, you can apply appropriate logic to rearrange the contents.

Check the below link:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html

Comment: Resizing puts zeros to end, then how am I gonna separate it from other (possible) zeros? What is the proper way of using resize?