# Python: Stretch and interpolate time series of unequal length

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with several time series `ta`, `tb` etc. below and corresponding measurements, given here by `av`, `bv`....

```
ta = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
av = np.random.rand(ta.shape[0], 1).flatten()
tb = np.arange(0, 1, 0.015)
bv = np.random.rand(tb.shape[0], 1).flatten()

d = {'ta': ta, 'a_val': av, 'tb':tb, 'b_val':bv}
pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in d.items() ]))
```

The time series all run from 0 to 1. I want to stretch and interpolate the shorter data so that they have the same number of rows.

I was going to use `pd.resample()` but it seems the data has to be in the date/time format for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the problem into two steps:

1. Stretch the shorter arrays (tb and bv)

After the creation of the arrays, following the suggestion of [mccandar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54346797/15197213), extend tb and bv using:

```
to = len(ta)

tb_resized  = np.repeat(np.nan,to)
foreign = np.linspace(0,to-1,len(tb)).round().astype(int)
tb_resized[foreign] = tb

bv_resized  = np.repeat(np.nan,to)
foreign = np.linspace(0,to-1,len(tb)).round().astype(int)
bv_resized[foreign] = bv
d = {'ta': ta, 'a_val': av, 'tb':tb_resized, 'b_val':bv_resized}
```

2. Interpolate.

Luckily, pandas makes this operation simple, through the [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) method!

```
pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in d.items()])).interpolate()
```